# Ansible - Show Output Progress in a Human Readable way

Tags: ansible

I have below ansible script which i used to install and update the new servers, however the output I get is very Unreadable (see output below), is there a way I can make it more user-friendly human readable output? at least converting "\n" to newlines.

Ansible script I run is

```py
    - name: "Core - Common - Centos Setup"
      hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      become_user: root
      tasks:
        - name: "Centos Version"
          shell: cat /etc/centos-release
          register: result
        - debug: var=result.stdout
    
        - name: 'Upgrade/Update all packages'
          yum:
            name: '*'
            state: latest
          register: result
        - debug: var=result
    
        - name: "Install nmap"
          package:
            name: nmap
            state: present
          register: result
        - debug: var=result
    
        - name: "Install wget"
          package:
            name: wget
            state: present
          register: result
        - debug: var=result
```

Output I get is similar to below...

```json
    TASK [Install nmap] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
    changed: [localhost]
    
    TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "result": {
            "changed": true,
            "changes": {
                "installed": [
                    "nmap"
                ]
            },
            "failed": false,
            "msg": "",
            "rc": 0,
            "results": [
                "Loaded plugins: langpacks\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package nmap.x86_64 2:6.40-19.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: nmap-ncat = 2:6.40-19.el7 for package: 2:nmap-6.40-19.el7.x86_64\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package nmap-ncat.x86_64 2:6.40-19.el7 will be installed\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n\nDependencies Resolved\n\n================================================================================\n Package         Arch         Version                Repository            Size\n================================================================================\nInstalling:\n nmap            x86_64       2:6.40-19.el7          base-openlogic       3.9 M\nInstalling for dependencies:\n nmap-ncat       x86_64       2:6.40-19.el7          base-openlogic       206 k\n\nTransaction Summary\n================================================================================\nInstall  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)\n\nTotal download size: 4.2 M\nInstalled size: 17 M\nDownloading packages:\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nTotal                                               14 MB/s | 4.2 MB  00:00     \nRunning transaction check\nRunning transaction test\nTransaction test succeeded\nRunning transaction\n  Installing : 2:nmap-ncat-6.40-19.el7.x86_64                               1/2 \n  Installing : 2:nmap-6.40-19.el7.x86_64                                    2/2 \n  Verifying  : 2:nmap-ncat-6.40-19.el7.x86_64                               1/2 \n  Verifying  : 2:nmap-6.40-19.el7.x86_64                                    2/2 \n\nInstalled:\n  nmap.x86_64 2:6.40-19.el7                                                     \n\nDependency Installed:\n  nmap-ncat.x86_64 2:6.40-19.el7                                                \n\nComplete!\n"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is some documentation about it like this : https://serverfault.com/questions/1011736/how-to-format-ansible-logs-in-a-human-readable-way , not sure if it matches your requirement 100%

Answer (score 1):

> at least converting "\n" to newlines.

If formatting the registered `result` is of importance to you, you can `split` it with the newline (`\n`) character.

Example:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result[0].split('\n') }}"
```

Also, as mentioned in the comment, setting `stdout_callback` will change the way task output is displayed.